# Set offset.storage.topic in connect-distributed.properties to use a different server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Im consuming from a kafka topic using kafka connect to load data into splunk. I donot want the offset to be stored on the same bootstrap server. I know we can set the offset.storage.topic property. But is there something like a offset.storage.Server property?

Below are a few properties from my connect-distributed.properties config.

```
bootstrap.servers=[server]

group.id=connect-cluster

plugin.path=/opt/kafka_2.12-2.2.0/plugins

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets

offset.storage.replication.factor=3
```

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you use the same server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe this is possible.

One option if you really don't want to write offsets back to the cluster is to run Kafka Connect in standalone mode, and have it use a local file instead for offsets. If you do that you can only run a single instance of the worker though so don't get any of the scalability and fault-tolerance benefits that distributed mode provides.